# How to replace HTML Text in an iFrame using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, text

I am wondering if it is possible to replace certain contents in an iFrame using jQuery `.html()` and/or `.text()`.

There is a span container that is rendered in the iFrame as follows:

```
<span id="article_3">
  <span>Headline News</span>
<span>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
<script>
  $("span#article_3 span").text("Trying to replace the text"); // does not work
  $("span#article_3 span").html("Trying to replace the text"); // does not work
</script>
```

Is it possible to do? Do I somehow need to fire my over-write script after the iframe has fully loaded?

Comment: If iframe is from same domain than main page, set it once iframe is fully loaded using `$("#myiframe").contents().find(span#article_3 span").text("Trying to replace the text");`. If different domain, you cannot access its content

Comment: Ok, thank you for that explanation @A.Wolff. It is, in fact from a different domain. So now I know...